# String replace with regex by using captured match as key

Tags: javascript, regex, string, replace

Let's say I have this string:

```
<i id="1"></i><i id="2"></i><i id="3"></i>
```

and this object:

```
{
  "1": "Red",
  "2": "Green",
  "3": "Blue"
}
```

Then I want to obtain this string:

```
<i color="Red"></i><i color="Green"></i><i color="Blue"></i>
```

Would be possible to make it through a regex replace?

I've tried this:

```
var stringIwant = stringIhave.replace(/id="(\d)"/g, 'color="' + myObject["$1"] + '"')
```

But it tries to read the property "$1" of the object, which doesn't exist. I also tried removing the quotes around $1:

```
var stringIwant = stringIhave.replace(/id="(\d)"/g, 'color="' + myObject[$1] + '"')
```

But I obtain a `ReferenceError: $1 is not defined`

I've tried more things, but nothing worth mentioning.

That's why I wonder if this is even possible. Any help?

Comment: Note that "color" is not a standard attribute for the HTML `<i>` tag, though you can use it for your own purposes.

Comment: Don't worry, it's an example I created to expose my problem

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can do that with callbacks:

```js
const stringIhave = `<i id="1"></i><i id="2"></i><i id="3"></i>`;

const obj = {
  "1": "Red",
  "2": "Green",
  "3": "Blue"
};

const stringIwant = stringIhave.replace(/id="(\d)"/g, (mat, grp) => `color="${obj[grp]}"`
);

console.log(stringIwant);
```

Answer (score 2):

You can take advantage of the fact that `.replace()` can be passed a *function* as the second parameter:

```
var stringIWant = stringIHave.replace(/id="(\d)"/g, function(wholeMatch, digits) {
  return "color='" + myObject[digits] + "'";
};
```

The first argument to such a function will be the entire match. The second and subsequent arguments will be the `( )` groups from your regex (if any). The returned value is used as the replacement for the entire match. When the regex has the "g" flag (as in your case), the function will be called on each match iteration.